# How to fix Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs?

Tags: android, android-studio, button, kotlin

I'm trying to add this beautiful menu button animation using this [Libary](https://github.com/michaldrabik/TapBarMenu) but when i try to run the app it's giving me this error this is [my APP](https://github.com/Aniskonig/myTapbar) HELP ME PLEASE!

> "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs"

[image]

Comment: You should try including the logs. It's very hard to help with the information you've provided.

Comment: Please download the app and try it

Answer (score 0):

As I am junior developer my solutios will not be the best but you can try this:

you have some code:

```
{1 line of code
2 line of code
3 line of code
4 line of code
}
```

Coment half of all lines

```
{1 line of code
2 line of code
//3 line of code
//4 line of code
   }
```

And then run aplication, if error is gone It means that comented lines of code is not good.
Then uncoment some lines and try again. Do this until you find the line which have some problem. And then repair that line

Comment: Thank you, you're at least better then anyone has ignore it